Load balancer, how to prevent requests to be forwarded to a target group without registered targets?
I have a load balancer with two target groups split evenly (50/50). The issue arises with one of the target groups, which may not have any registered targets throughout the day. During this time, the load balancer forwards requests to this target group without any targets, resulting in 5xx errors.
My objective is to only forward requests to target groups with registered targets without deregistering the target group from the load balancer when it has no targets.
The health check does not work in this scenario because there are no targets to verify its health status to now forward
